# Don't worry, I won't byte

Tags: cipher

... I am pretty hungry though. Figure out what I want to eat:

> 01001001 00011111 01000100 10110100 11110101 10010001 00011111 01000001 10111101 10110011 01100000 01100110 10000110 11000010 10001000 10010001 01001010 01010000 10001100 11001111 10101100 10001000 11111010 00011101 00100110

When it matters, you'll need to know that the last two get capitalized.

**Bonus:**
Encode the answer the same way I encoded the question.

**Hint 1:**

> Look at the title to see how it's NOT encoded.

Comment: Looks like binary but not straight to text... You might want to grab a snack.

Comment: I'd say with capitalization mattering, maybe it goes through ASCII codes?

Comment: @Raystafarian Apparently not: http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-ascii-text-converter

Comment: @Raystafarian It's definitely not ASCII; the high bit is set for about half the octets.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a variant on the Bacon cipher. Each group of five digits encodes a letter by converting it from binary to A-Z, with 00001=A, 00010=B, and so on.

The message is: `I DOT IMGUR DOT COM SLASH M P THREE E A C FOUR DOT GIF`

This points to the image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9hCU.gif, which shows a pizza.

Comment: Dang, beat me by just a few seconds =)

Comment: did the hint give it away or would you have had it without the hint?

Comment: @MisterEman22 I got it after seeing the hint, but it would have been possible without it.